# jQuery autocomplete source parameter does not update

Tags: jquery, input, autocomplete, radio-button

I'm using the jQuery autocomplete script for a text input element but the problem is that the lang variable in the source URI doesn't update when the variable is updated.

The value of lang is updated whenever I click on a radio input element and after that I type something in the text input element which then trigger the autocomplete code. Strangely enough it always uses the "en" value and not the updated value.

Does anyone know a better approach or a fix for my code?

**code:**

```
var lang = 'en';

$('input[name="language"]').click(function()
{
    lang= $(this).val();
});

$("#query").autocomplete({
    source: "domain.com/suggest.php?language=" + lang,
    minLength: 1
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to a create custom AJAX call:

```
    source: function(request, response)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'domain.com/suggest.php',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {language: $('input[name="language"]:checked').val(), term: $('#query').val()},
            success: response
        });
    },
```

Hope this helps others too.

Answer (score 1):

The click event occurs when you click on the select, not when you change values.  So lang is probably getting reassigned to the current value of the select, which if it's english it will remain english after having changed the select value.  What you probably mean to do is:

```
$('input[name="language"]').change(function()
{
    lang= $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: Why not just use $('input[name="language"]').val() instead of the lang var right away?

Comment: Because getting the value from the checked radio button (`$('input[name="language"]:checked').val()`) didn't work either. Thinking it had something to do with the checked option of the radio buttons causing problems I hoped for this method to solve it. Unfortunately it has the same result.

Comment: If $('input[name="language"]').val() doesn't return the selected value, then there's your problem. (use console.log() and Firebug to verify)

Comment: That jQuery code returns the correct value but the problem is that the source part of the autocomplete code doesn't use the updated value. When I changed it to a function, strangely enough it outputted the correct value. The code is: `source: function(){alert(lang)}`

Answer (score 0):

You should embed the autocomplete function inside the click or change function so that each time you select a different radio button, the autocomplete is initialized again:

```
var lang = 'en';

$('input[name="language"]').click(function()
{
    lang= $(this).val();


$("#query").autocomplete({
    source: "domain.com/suggest.php?language=" + lang,
    minLength: 1
});

});
```